# clojure friendly java library for traversing NAT

Tags: java, clojure, nat

I need to be able to establish a connection between two boxes that are both behind NAT? I have a central system that both sides can find each other through. I'm working in Clojure.

Comment: Are these boxes behind the same NAT router?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to do UDP, take a look at [stun4j](https://stun4j.dev.java.net/).  Otherwise, I think you may need to roll your own code from scratch.

But it would help a lot if you provided more information about what you were trying to do.